# open source Dosware Payment Gateway (Dopays.com) configration error

Tags: php, mysql, open-source

I am trying to use Dosware Payment Gateway (Dopays.com) on my local machine where I have windows 7 installed with wamp server. I modified the connection in the config.htm file according to instructions given in install.txt file.I dont know where I am doing wrong but when i run the project via localhost in the browser i get nothing just a blank html page.

I have modified config.htm as:

```
<?
################################################################################
$db_hostname='localhost';
$db_username='root';
$db_password='r00t';
$db_database='dopays_base';
$db_tbprefix='dp';
################################################################################
$folder='dopays/demo';
################################################################################





################################################################################
###    PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE ANY PARAMETERS MANUALLY! USE ADMIN AREA FOR IT   ###
################################################################################
$site_name='Dopays.com';
$site_title='The First Open Source Payment System';
$site_charset='iso-8859-1';
$site_copyrights='©2002-2004 DOSWARE TEAM';
$site_keywords='Site keywords should be here.';
$site_description='Site description should be here.';

$admin_email='Dopays.com<source@dopays.com>';
$admin_username='admin';
$admin_password='admin';
$admin_check_ip=false;
$admin_ip_address='';

$protect_html='';

$mail_address='Your psyhical address should be here.';

$passlen=8;
$passatt=5;
$currency='$';
$currsize='3';
$dateformat='m/d/Y h:iA';

$use_turing=true;
$use_numbers=true;
$turing_size=8;
$turing_quality=75;
$turing_bgfile='images/turing_bg.jpg';
$use_extreg=true;

$signup_use=true;
$signup_bonus=100.000;
$maxemails=3;

$minimal_transfer=0.050;
$maximal_transfer=100.000;
$transfer_percent=2.000;
$transfer_fee=0.250;
$refund_period=30;

$affiliate_program=true;
$affiliate_levels=6;
$affiliate_percent=3.000;

$dep_minimal=1.000;
$dep_maximal=500.000;
$dep_pp_use=false;
$dep_pp_fee=0.500;
$dep_pp_percent=2.500;
$dep_pp_username='';
$dep_pp_password='';
$dep_sp_use=false;
$dep_sp_fee=0.500;
$dep_sp_percent=2.500;
$dep_sp_username='';
$dep_sp_password='';
$dep_np_use=false;
$dep_np_fee=1.000;
$dep_np_percent=5.500;
$dep_np_username='';
$dep_np_password='';
$dep_eg_use=true;
$dep_eg_fee=1.000;
$dep_eg_percent=15.000;
$dep_eg_username='7';
$dep_eg_password='';
$dep_mb_use=false;
$dep_mb_fee=1.000;
$dep_mb_percent=2.000;
$dep_mb_username='';
$dep_mb_password='';
$dep_ig_use=false;
$dep_ig_fee=0.500;
$dep_ig_percent=2.500;
$dep_ig_username='';
$dep_ig_password='';
$dep_eb_use=false;
$dep_eb_fee=0.500;
$dep_eb_percent=1.500;
$dep_eb_username='';
$dep_eb_password='';
$dep_px_use=false;
$dep_px_fee=1.000;
$dep_px_percent=1.000;
$dep_px_username='';
$dep_px_password='';
$dep_pd_use=false;
$dep_pd_fee=1.000;
$dep_pd_percent=1.000;
$dep_pd_username='';
$dep_pd_password='';
$dep_ev_use=false;
$dep_ev_fee=1.000;
$dep_ev_percent=5.500;
$dep_ev_username='';
$dep_ev_password='';
$dep_qc_use=true;
$dep_qc_fee=10.000;
$dep_qc_percent=2.500;
$dep_qc_username='1';
$dep_qc_password='';
$dep_gm_use=true;
$dep_gm_fee=1.000;
$dep_gm_percent=2.540;
$dep_gm_username='H';
$dep_gm_password='';
$dep_vg_use=false;
$dep_vg_fee=1.000;
$dep_vg_percent=1.500;
$dep_vg_username='';
$dep_vg_password='';
$dep_pe_use=false;
$dep_pe_fee=1.000;
$dep_pe_percent=2.530;
$dep_pe_username='';
$dep_pe_password='';
$dep_an_use=false;
$dep_an_fee=0.500;
$dep_an_percent=5.500;
$dep_an_username='';
$dep_an_password='';
$dep_cc_use=false;
$dep_cc_fee=0.500;
$dep_cc_percent=5.500;
$dep_cc_username='';
$dep_cc_password='';
$dep_ec_use=true;
$dep_ec_fee=0.500;
$dep_ec_percent=5.500;
$dep_ec_username='';
$dep_ec_password='';
$dep_mc_use=true;
$dep_mc_fee=0.500;
$dep_mc_percent=5.500;
$dep_mc_username='';
$dep_mc_password='';

$wdr_minimal=30.000;
$wdr_maximal=500.000;
$wdr_pp_use=true;
$wdr_pp_fee=1.000;
$wdr_sp_use=true;
$wdr_sp_fee=1.000;
$wdr_np_use=true;
$wdr_np_fee=1.000;
$wdr_eg_use=true;
$wdr_eg_fee=1.000;
$wdr_mb_use=true;
$wdr_mb_fee=2.000;
$wdr_ig_use=true;
$wdr_ig_fee=1.000;
$wdr_eb_use=true;
$wdr_eb_fee=1.000;
$wdr_px_use=true;
$wdr_px_fee=1.000;
$wdr_pd_use=true;
$wdr_pd_fee=1.000;
$wdr_ev_use=true;
$wdr_ev_fee=1.000;
$wdr_gm_use=true;
$wdr_gm_fee=2.000;
$wdr_vg_use=true;
$wdr_vg_fee=3.000;
$wdr_pe_use=true;
$wdr_pe_fee=4.000;
$wdr_bw_use=true;
$wdr_bw_fee=35.000;
$wdr_mc_use=true;
$wdr_mc_fee=2.000;
$wdr_wu_use=true;
$wdr_wu_fee=10.000;
$wdr_mg_use=true;
$wdr_mg_fee=10.000;
################################################################################
include('consts.htm');
include('common.htm');
################################################################################
?>
```

Any help on this topic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the $folder variable is set to the root of your site. I set mine to blank since I serving the index.htm from the root of my site

$folder='';

Hope this helps

Comment: also make sure that short_open_tag is enabled on your server